# How do I open a bank account in Japan without a residence card?

Tags: japan, money

I will be flying to Japan next month for work. I have obtained the Certificate of Eligibility which is valid for 3 months from my employer in Japan. I have a short term visa which is valid for 3 month therefore, I cannot get a residence card. I want to know how can I open a bank account without a residence card which is required for opening a bank account?

Comment: I don't think you can without a residence card. This strongly suggests you have the wrong visa.  The short stay visa can't be used for paid activities.

Comment: @xuq01 There is no such thing as "the short stay visa". Many types of visas can be issued for short periods, including so-called "work visas".

Comment: @fkraiem My COE is valid for 3 months only and I have just applied for VISA with long stay. My COE status is “Engineer/Specialist in Humanities/ Int’l services”

Comment: Then you will get a residence card when you enter Japan, provided that your visa is for a period of stay longer than three months. Why do you say you have a short term visa?

Comment: @fkraiem Based on the validity of COE

Comment: The validity period of the CoE is not related to the allowed period of stay in Japan (the CoE need only be valid when you enter Japan).

Comment: Or do you mean that your CoE says "3 months" in the "Status" box? In that case, you will get a period of stay of 3 months, and no residence card. If you think that is not normal, you should contact your employer.

Comment: @fkraiem Thank you :) I will check with my employer

Comment: Although this question is flagged "off-topic", I still want to gave you a proper answer. You will use COE to apply for a long term (working) VISA, 1, 3, 5 years depends on your company. At the airport, you show the customs your passport (with long term VISA), they will give you a residence card. Then you will use it, along with the contract from you company to contact the bank to open an account.